# How can I get the transit time for packets for a jitter buffer?

Tags: networking, estimation, tcp

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of a real jitter buffer. I'm basing the only knowledge that I have around this article:

http://toncar.cz/Tutorials/VoIP/VoIP_Basics_Jitter.html

This article states that:

> In the jitter estimator formula, the value D(i-1, i) is the
>   difference of relative transit times for the two packets. The
>   difference is computed as
>
> D(i,j) = (Rj - Ri) - (Sj - Si) = (Rj - Sj) - (Ri - Si)
>
> Si is the timestamp from the packet i and Ri is the time of arrival
>   for packet i.

I've been trying to figure out in my head how it's possible to get the time it takes a packet to get from one system to the other even using TCP. If I'm not mistaken, won't the timestamps on the two devices be out of sync even if I were to send them as headers? Even if I were to sync timestamps before beginning pushing out the audio data, wouldn't that be received several milliseconds afterwards making syncing not possible?

So my question is, how can I actually calculate how long it takes for packets to arrive at their destination to calculate jitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute time it takes for packets to arrive at their destination is called *latency*.  Jitter is the *relative difference* between those times.  The distinction is important, because due to a fortunate quirk of the math, you don't actually need to know the latency in order to calculate the jitter.

Let's say the sender's clock is `t` milliseconds faster than the receiver's clock.  `t` changes over time due to drift, but in the 20 milliseconds between packets, that drift is essentially negligible.  That means we must add `t` to every receiver timestamp in order to synchronize it with the sender's timestamp.  Correcting for the unsynchronized clocks, the formula becomes:

```
D(i,j) = ((Rj + t) - (Ri + t)) - (Sj - Si)
```

Notice anything?  Because we are only interested in the *difference* between timestamps, the `t` cancels out!  If we really want to calculate `t`, and subsequently the latency, we can do it using techniques I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755890), but it's not necessary if we only care about jitter.

Comment: Okay. That makes a lot of sense, but could I ask what the D(i,j) = means? Is it supposed to represent a point? Also, I could understand Ri would mean the received time for this current iteration, but what does Rj mean? Thanks so much.

Comment: `i` and `j` are two consecutive packets.  `Rj` is the receiver's timestamp for the current packet and `Ri` is the receiver's timestamp on the previous packet.  `D(i,j)` is the difference in transit time between the two packets.